# why am i getting the wrong answer for the index of the number whos left sum=right sum in the list

Tags: python, list

please tell my mistake
i m getting the index of the number whose leftsum=rightsum wrong

```
L=[]
n=int(input("enter the number of values to be added to the list: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    k=int(input("enter the values: "))
    L.append(k)

for i in range(0,n):
    if sum(range(L[0],L[i])) == sum(range(L[i+1],L[-1])):
        print(L.index(L[i]))
        break
    else:
        print("0")
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: what is the mistake i did in the code

Comment: Why do you think that there is a mistake?

Comment: i m getting the wrong answer

Comment: What answer do you get and what would be the correct answer?

Comment: When you ask what is wrong, you should at least tell us what result you actually got and what result you expected. Please read [ask]

Comment: if i input values [1,2,3,80,3,3]
i want the answer as 3

Comment: this is my first time posting on stackoverflow

Comment: @JeevanBA I've posted an answer. Check it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @AshutoshPorwal i m getting the wrong answer only dude

Comment: @JeevanBA Updated the code, check again.

Comment: @AshutoshPorwal its working bro thanks

Comment: @AshutoshPorwal but why did u take elif i=n-1 . I didnt understand that. why cant why simply take else print("0")

Comment: @JeevanBA Then the program would print 0 on every iteration. I put the condition to check if I've reached through to the end of the list. Try removing it and check the output.

Comment: @AshutoshPorwal if we need it reach the end we should put i=n instead of i=n-1 right

Comment: @JeevanBA No. The index of a list ranges from 0 to n-1. You get n values that way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For starters, you've used `range(a,b)`, which returns all the numbers from `a` to `b-1`

Try this:

```py
L=[]
n=int(input("enter the number of values to be added to the list: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    k=int(input("enter the values: "))
    L.append(k)
    

for i in range(1,n):
    if sum(L[0:i]) == sum(L[i+1:]):
        print(L.index(L[i]))
        break
    elif i==n-1:
        print(0)
```